# Can´t load a program into my ESP01 using an ArduinoUno

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, wifi, error

This is my problem,  I´ve been trying to load a program(any program) into mi ESP01 and because I do not have the usb adapter, I decided to use my Arduino Uno to do the work.

This is my first time working with this board (ESP01), and in my search I found that it is important to have GIO0 LOW ,GIO2, RST and in HIGH to upload a program; besides I already have this board into the list that Arduino´s IDE have and I used 3.3v for VCC.  Yet, when I try to upload a program, the IDE wont let me because of this error: esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Invalid head of packet (0xF0

The program that I want to try is the HelloServer example.

[image: This is the circuit]

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: the sketch in Uno should not have Serial.begin(). make it simpler by pulling down io 0 all the time why you try flash the esp (remove the switch)

Comment: I would not trust breadboard connections for RX voltage divider. you can test it by wiring RX without voltage divider. esp8266 can tolerate 5 V on pull-up current levels used with TTL Serial.